# suid executable not elevating permissions but `sudo` does elevate

Tags: setuid

I'm trying to write a program that will quickly shut down a laptop without prompting for a password or confirmation. The laptop is running Linux, specifically Manjaro.

To that end, I'm trying to make a `setuid` executable called `downnow` that executes `shutdown` with fixed arguments (and also spawns a shell). I'm only using `system` here to keep the program short, it's a terrible idea from a security standpoint.

```
// downnow.c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("shutdown --no-wall --halt now");
  return 0;
}
```

then I compiled `downnow`, moved it to `/bin`, changed its owner and gave it setuid and setgid permissions:

```
$ sudo chown root /bin/downnow 

$ sudo chgrp root /bin/downnow 

$ sudo chmod u+s /bin/downnow 

$ sudo chmod g+s /bin/downnow
```

However, when I attempt to execute `downnow` as an unprivileged user, it can't communicate with systemd.

```
$ downnow 
Failed to halt system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

I get the same message before and after `ch{own,grp,mod}`ing.

`stat` reports the same permissions on `/bin/downnow` and `/usr/bin/sudo`.

```
$ stat /bin/downnow 
  File: /bin/downnow
  Size: XXXX        Blocks: XX         IO Block: XXXX   regular file
Device: XXXXX/XXXXX Inode: XXXXXX     Links: 1
Access: (6755/-rwsr-sr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)

$ stat /usr/bin/sudo
  File: /usr/bin/sudo
  Size: XXXXXX      Blocks: XXX        IO Block: XXXX   regular file
Device: XXXXX/XXXXX Inode: XXXXXXX     Links: 1
Access: (4755/-rwsr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

Why might `downnow` fail to elevate its privileges when `sudo` works perfectly?

Comment: Another approach is not writing any set-UID program at all, and setting up a PolicyKit rule.  Most people want to disable the ability to shutdown.  Enabling it is an exercise in the converse.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263884/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491038/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably due to a lack of a `setuid(2)` call. Here's a before and after around such a call:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define GETUIDS(p) (p[0]=getuid(),p[1]=geteuid())

int main(void)
{
    uid_t ids[2];
    GETUIDS(ids);
    fprintf(stderr, "real %lu effective %lu\n", (unsigned long) ids[0],
            (unsigned long) ids[1]);
    if (setuid(0) == -1)
        err(1, "setuid failed");
    GETUIDS(ids);
    fprintf(stderr, "real %lu effective %lu\n", (unsigned long) ids[0],
            (unsigned long) ids[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Also your wrapper is not really safe; hopefully it will not escape to multi-user systems. It would be likely much safer to avoid the needless shell call (unless you like shellshock type vulnerabilities or the strange handling of duplicate environment variables by, say, `bash`...) and instead use an `exec(3)` call to replace your process with `shutdown` directly:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    if (setuid(0) == -1)
        err(1, "setuid failed");
    //execl("/usr/bin/echo", "echo", "--no-wall", "--halt", "now",
    execl("/usr/sbin/shutdown", "shutdown", "--no-wall", "--halt", "now",
          (char *) 0);
    err(1, "exec failed");
    return 1;
}
```

A few accidental shutdowns later...

```
centos7# make badcode
cc     badcode.c   -o badcode
centos7# mv badcode /badcode
centos7# chmod u+s /badcode
centos7# su - jhqdoe
Last login: Thu Jan 10 01:39:03 UTC 2019 on pts/0
[jhqdoe@centos7 ~]$ /badcode
Connection to 192.168.99.2 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.99.2 closed.
```

Comment: The part that everyone is missing is that `Interactive authentication required.` results from the PolicyKit rules processing, which does not happen in-process and which tests the effective UID not the real UID.

Comment: @JdeBP huh? maybe post how you think policykit is involved in an answer? where did you pull `Interactive authentication required` from?

Comment: From the question.

Comment: @JdeBP yes, and? PolicyKit intrudes without the necessary `setuid` call, and does not with the `setuid` call and appropriate ownership and `u+s` bit set, as a trivial test on, say, Centos 7 will show.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the permission bit only allows your application to use the `setuid` call and doesn't, by itself, change your permissions. To do that, you need to set the uid with `setuid(uid_t uid)`. See the man page for details: https://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid

You can use `geteuid()` to get the current effective uid (i.e. the owner of the file with the setuid permission). See man page: https://linux.die.net/man/2/geteuid

Example:

```
// downnow.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  setuid(geteuid());
  system("shutdown --no-wall --halt now");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That explanation will probably just confuse people.  The set-ID permissions very much _do_ change one's credentials.  Indeed, you are copying those very changed effective credentials onto the real ones.