# How to make reboot require an admin password

Tags: raspbian, shutdown, reboot

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Buster. It happens sometimes that I misclick on "shutdown" or "reboot" instead of just Logout. And this is very annoying espcially when I click on Shutdown.. How can I make Raspbian require a sudoer password to reboot or shutdown my Pi (in UI)?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209766/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/491038/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289123/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/263884/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253767/5132 .